# How Do I add my backup database to my site that was genereated from mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

Would I have to just cut and past?

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump does not generate CREATE DATABASE statment so you have to create database first

1. CREATE DATABASE some_db;
2. login into mysql
3. use some_db
4. mysql> source /path/of/sql/file/backup.sql
5. Change the database setting in your application file to point new DB

That's it.

Comment: sure it does, unless you specifically disable it, mysqldump's output is everything needed to recreate the database, including CREATE TABLE. the `-n` option suppresses the create statements.

Comment: @Marc: I am assuming he has CREATE TABLE because he asked he is creating copy of DB

Comment: Ah, doh. right. Mybad. Must remember to wake up in the mornings.

Comment: @asaf: If this helped, Please consider to accept the answer, You can accept by clicking right arrow sign at the left of this answer